# istream extraction operator: how to detect parse failure?

Tags: c++, parsing, istream

How can I detect whether the istream extraction failed like this?

```
string s("x");
stringstream ss(s);
int i;
ss >> std::ios::hex >> i;
```

EDIT -- Though the question title covers this, I forgot to mention in the body: I really want to detect whether the failure is due to bad formatting, i.e. parsing, or due to any other IO-related issue, in order to provide proper feedback (an malformed_exception("x") or whatever).

Comment: I don't think you can use stream manipulators with `operator>>`?

Comment: @jrok: according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/operator%3E%3E/, you can.

Comment: Yes, that was new to me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: thanks for the useful answers.  However, after some investigation (cfr. [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios_base/iostate/)) and verification, it seems that the one way to check for parse-failure only is by checking for the `ios::failbit` flag, as in

```
const bool parsing_failed = (ss >> ios::hex >> i).rdstate() & ios::failbit ;
```

While both the suggested `istream::operator!` and `istream::operator bool` mingle `failbit` *and* `badbit` (cfr [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_not/) and [there](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/) on cplusplusreference).

Comment: It certainly looks complicated - I need to look this up again in order to understand it :(.  What kind of wrong do _you_ mean?

Answer (score 9):

```
if(! (ss >> std::ios::hex >> i) ) 
{
  std::cerr << "stream extraction failed!" << std::endl;
}
```

It's just that easy.

ETA: Here's an example of how this test interacts with the end of a stream.

```
int i;
std::stringstream sstr("1 2 3 4");
while(sstr >> i)
{
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    if(sstr.eof())
    {
        std::cout << "eof" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

will print
1
2
3
4
eof

If you were to check `sstr.eof()` or `sstr.good()` in the while loop condition, 4 would not be printed.

Comment: Thanks; indeed, it catches bad parsing.  However, it also catches any other `bad()` situation (cfr http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/).  I believe testing for the `sstr.rdstate() & ios::failbit` would be more accurate.

Comment: If you were to check `sstr.eof()` in the while loop condition, 4 would be printed.

Comment: @ctn `while(sstr>> i && !(sstr.eof()))` would fail to print 4, which I believe is what I had in mind when I wrote what I did back in 2011. On the other hand, either `while(!(sstr.eof()) && sstr >> i)` or `while(!(sstr.eof())) { sstr>>i` will print 4. Looking at it now, that last formulation is a more intuitive reading.

Comment: Yes, the last formulation is what I had in mind too. It also seems more useful when checking errors: `while (!sstr.eof()) { if (!(sstr >> i)) { error("not a number"); } }`

Answer (score 4):

Failure to extract the value will set the stream's "fail" bit, which can be detected by `if (ss.fail())`, or just `if (!ss)`. Equivalently, you can test the result of the `>>` operation, since that returns a reference to the stream.

These will also detect other errors, which set the "bad" bit; you can distinguish these with `ss.bad()`.

If you want to continue reading from the stream, you'll need to clear the state flags (`ss.clear()`).

Comment: `ss.bad()` and `!ss` test two different things. First tests for underlying media failure (badbit), while the other tests for that and additionally for formatted input failure (badbit | failbit).

Comment: @wilx: Yes, I got "bad" and "fail" mixed up. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Errors during extraction are signaled by the internal state flags.
You can check them by the `good()` member function.
See also here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream

Or just using the `if()`-construction as suggested above.
This works due to the bool cast operator of stream classes

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  Did you realize that your answer gets above the 'suggestion above' if it were accepted?