# class object is not reading from text file using fsream

Tags: c++, class, fstream

Hi I am having an issue with fstream variable. my movie class can't read info from the a text file:

here is the output is produces:

```
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 Ì -858993460 -858993460 -9.25596e+061 -858993460 -858993460
```

and it SHOULD produce:

```
 110 8.3 2005 275523 A 140 Batman begins
 123 8.2 1965 45515 W 132 For a Few Dollars More
 181 8.1 1946 17648 R 172 The Best Years of Our Lives
 30 8.6 1946 103101 D 130 it's a Wonderful Life
 77 8.3 1952 56368 C 103 Singin' in the Rain
 88 8.3 1995 245089 A 177 Braveheart
 45 8.5 2001 185124 C 122 Amelie
 48 8.5 1962 80746 V 216 Lawrence of Arabia
```

and input text is:

```
 110 8.3 2005 275523 A 140 Batman begins
 123 8.2 1965 45515 W 132 For a Few Dollars More
 181 8.1 1946 17648 R 172 The Best Years of Our Lives
 30 8.6 1946 103101 D 130 it's a Wonderful Life
 77 8.3 1952 56368 C 103 Singin' in the Rain
 88 8.3 1995 245089 A 177 Braveheart
 45 8.5 2001 185124 C 122 Amelie
 48 8.5 1962 80746 V 216 Lawrence of Arabia
 -1
```

At this point I am having a hard time understanding why it's doing that. I am using MS VS2008.

here is the code:

```
#include "movieType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
movieType movie[9];
ifstream inFile("movie1.txt");

int i =0;

bool notDone=true;
while (notDone) 
{ 
    if (movie[i++].readMovieInfo(inFile)== false)
        notDone=false;    
}

for (int i=0;i<8;++i)
{
    movie[i].printMovieInfo("printList.txt");
}

return 0;
}
```

and the class specification

```
#include <string>
//include preprocessor directive to give access to string operations

class movieType
{
public:
    movieType();
    //Function: Class constructor
    //Precondition: none
    //Postcondition: instance variable initialized

    ~movieType();
    //Function: class destructor
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition: memory allocated to class object freed up

    bool readMovieInfo(std::ifstream&);
    //Function: reads one movie at one time from a file
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition: return false if the rank is <1 else return true

    void printMovieInfo(char*);
    //Function:prints one movie at a time to a file
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition: none

    char getGenre();
    //Function: returns the movie genre
    //Precondition:object has been initialized
    //Postcondition: none

    int getRank();
    //Function: returns the movie rank
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition: none

    bool operator>=(movieType) const;
    //Function: overload operator for '<=' for use in heap
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition:none

    bool operator>(movieType) const;
    //Function: overload operator for '<' for use in heap
    //Precondition: object has been initialized
    //Postcondition:none

private:
    int rank; //movie ranking
    double weight; //calculated wieght for ranking
    int year; //year the movie was released
    int votes; //number of votes 
    char genre; //movie genre
    int length; //movie length in minute
    std::string name; //the name of the movie

};
```

and the class implementation:

```
#include "movieType.h"
//preprocessor directive gives access to movieType class
#include <fstream>
//preprocessor directive gives access fstream operations
#include <string>
//preprocessor directive gives access string operations

using namespace std;
// make fstream and string operations available without calling class std


movieType::movieType()
{
}

movieType::~movieType()
{
}

bool movieType::readMovieInfo(ifstream& inFile)
{
    inFile>>rank>>weight>>year>>votes>>genre>>length;
    getline(inFile,name);

    if (rank < 1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

void movieType::printMovieInfo(char* outFileName)
{
std::ofstream outFile;
if(!outFile.is_open()) 
    outFile.open(outFileName, std::ios::app);
outFile<<name<<" "<<year<<" "<<genre<<" "<<length<<" "<<rank;
outFile<<" "<<weight<<" "<<year<<" "<<votes<<std::endl;

}
int movieType::getRank()
{
return rank;
}

char movieType::getGenre()
{
return genre;
}

bool movieType::operator >=(movieType other) const
{
if (rank >= other.rank)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}

bool movieType::operator >(movieType other) const
{
if (rank > other.rank)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I created a text file with your "SHOULD produce" example, tested the code, and got the correct results. Please show **exactly** what the text file looks like, as it is different than the code you show under "SHOULD produce". (Also, you should always check that *all* reads and writes where performed correctly, as the problem is that your stream is failing somewhere probably).

Comment: I am pretty new to c++. How would you check that all read and writes were performed correctly?

Comment: I've linked to a good writeup in my response.

Comment: @jesseGood, I ran my prgm again and I get the same results as I have posted. I am curious on how you can run the same program and get the correct output.

Comment: @user1561949: See my answer and let me know if my assumption is incorrect. I suspect that file path is wrong.

Comment: @Jesse Good: Since I started using fstream, I have always include the input text file in the same folder as main.cpp and it always worked. and I did the same thing here. How do I fix the file path?

Comment: @user1561949: Stuff like that gets OS specific. Look into [SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and don't forget to include `windows.h`. Also, make sure that you just didn't misspell the file name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is the following line:

```
ifstream inFile("movie1.txt");
```

Basically, you never checked that the file was opened successfully.

Try, the following, and tell me what it outputs:

```
if (!inFile)
{
    std::cout << "Could not open file" << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

I bet that it tells you the file could not be opened.

Also, to check that the read were successful, do:

```
if(!(inFile>>rank>>weight>>year>>votes>>genre>>length))
{
     // Something went wrong
}
```

However, it might be better to break that up a bit.

Comment: :) you won the bet! The file could not be opened. I am in a bind, how can i open it then it the file can't be opened?

Comment: @user1561949: The easiest way is to specify the full path, i.e. `c:/mydirectory/blah/movie1.txt` or if you know the relative path example: `debug/movie1.txt`.

Comment: here is what I wrote, but I still can't open the file:    <pre> ifstream inFile("C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/131part1/131part1/movie1.txt") <code>

Comment: @user1561949: Okay, to figure out the problem, check the [errno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) value, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503878/how-to-know-what-the-errno-means) for an example.

Comment: Good: I had made a stupid mistake. I had saved the input file as: movie1.txt.txt Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely case is that stream reading fails, in which case all the `movieType` instances will go uninitialized. You should be checking the stream for errors and handle them appropriately, i.e. `if (inFile.fail()) { ... }` or just `if (!inFile)`.

So basically you're printing uninitialized (i.e. random) memory.

**The IOStream operators in C++ don't usually throw exceptions, it is absolutely crucial to do manual error checking.**

[See this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488937/istream-extraction-operator-how-to-detect-parse-failure) for a good writeup of the topic.